# Word or expression for this kind of person

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, epithet-requests

What to call a person who has always had advantages in his whole life and career because of his family's social/political status. Obviously most of the time these people, usually youngsters, are found in countries with systematic corruption.

Can the word "princeling" be used?

Comment: You have a grammatical error in your question, Rha. 'What is called a person who has ... status?' should be either  'What is the name for a person who has ... status?' or  'What is a person who has ... status called?'. The way you put it is used to ask for definitions as in 'What is called an SUV?' but even that is more likely to be asked as 'What is an SUV?'

Comment: I ain't me, I ain't no millionaire's sooooon

Comment: a spoiled brat.

Answer (score 1):

To express this, you can use the idiom ***born with a silver spoon in one's mouth***. It means "born into wealth and privilege". For example, *James doesn't know anything about working for a living; he was born with a silver spoon in his mouth.*

A ***rich kid*** would also do. Rich kids are young people or young adults pampered beyond the point where they realise they are lucky; fully expectant of an idle life of luxury and not aware that some people have to work (Urban Dictionary). Note that it's about young people. If you talk about a person who is not young but has always been lucky in this way, use the idiom above.

Answer (score 1):

Another word describing a rich, spoiled person or child is entitled, which implies an attitude of entitlement as well, i.e., having the expectation of receiving favored treatment.